# Sum column multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a table with some products. Each of them have a price.
When a user sees his basket, I want to display the total amount of all the products he selected.

My question is : is it possible to do it via SQL or have I to do it after the request in PHP ?

Actually my request is :

```sql
SELECT SUM(PRICE) FROM products WHERE ID IN(65,68,68);
```

And I would the two 68 to be taken in consideration.

Thank you,
Florian

Comment: you're passing the id's in the in by parameter ?

Comment: Are you saving the user's basket in your database? Or is it just in your session object or a cookie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So ideally you would not use `IN` in this case (in fact, you can't get it to work that way). What you need is a JOIN to the cart_products table (or similar):

```
SELECT SUM(PRICE) 
FROM 
  cart_products
  JOIN products ON products.id = cart_products.product_id
WHERE 
  cart_products.cart_id = ?
```

And then pass in the current session's cart_id.

Note that if your cart has a qty option, you can use this as the SUM expression:

```
SUM(products.PRICE * cart_products.qty)
```

Comment: Why? if there are three rows in cart_products with product_id 68, then it will do 68.price * 3. However if the cart uses a qty attribute instead, see the edit.

Comment: +1 This does of course assume there is a `cart_products` table in the first place.

Comment: @lc. yup. And if there isn't one, OP should take it as a hint of advice ;-)

Comment: Thank you, I think I will use your second solution. Actually my basket system is under development, and I had not planned to have a table like what you suggest. I was thinking about storing my Basket class instance (which contains product instances) serialized in a table (1 column=[1 SID, 1 Basket]). Is my solution completely crazy ? (I ask because it is so far from what you've proposed !). Thank you in advance, Florian

Comment: It is definitely recommended that the cart be stored in the database (and I'm assuming you at least know why completed orders should be stored this way). With a structure like this, you afford yourself many options for leveraging that data which are not possible with serialized carts. For instance, should active-carts affect inventories/availability? Do you want efficient reporting on abandoned carts? Do you want to query for items "related to" items in the active cart? Do you want the user to be able to be associated with several carts?, etc....

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I'm not sure if we understand ourselves. With what I was thinking about, **the cart would be saved in the database** ! I would have a column named SID, which contains the PHPSESSID cookie value, and linked to it, the serialized cart. I would unserialize it when the user comes to the website : `SELECT cart FROM table WHERE SID=COOKIE` ; `unserialize(cart)` (or `create(cart)` if no SQL answer). So I would be able to do operations like you mentioned with this system no ?
For your solution : you would create a table like this : SID1|Pdt1 ; SID1|Pdt2 ; SID2:Pdt1 ?

Comment: There's a difference between storing it in the DB and being able to use SQL to leverage it :-) The structure should be something like: `create table cart_products (id, cart_id, product_id, at_price, qty)` (which implies that there is also a carts table: `create table carts (id, user_id, last_modified, ...)`)

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I'm new in e-commerce based architecture !
Last question I promise : if I understand the `user_id` field is the PHPSESSID ?
Florian

Comment: No, ideally you will do similar DB-modeling for your customers, right? Your PHPSESSID should indicate which session to pull, and the session will indicate which user owns that session (perhaps with a special case for anonymous, perhaps not). This way you can facilitate saving the cart for later (i.e. same user, different session)

Comment: Also, welcome to StackOverflow! Be sure to accept an answer whenever appropriate, as it helps the community, you, and the answerers.

Comment: Okay, that's approximately what I planned. The SID will serve me to recognize anonymous users, because I don't think there is an other way to identify them when they leave and come back.
Thank you very much !! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically generate your SQL so you end up with something like:

```
SELECT SUM(PRICE)
FROM
(
    SELECT PRICE FROM products WHERE id = 65
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PRICE FROM products WHERE id = 68
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PRICE FROM products WHERE id = 68
) x
```

but I wonder if there's really a point. Presumably you already have the unit price displayed on the page, so can't you just add it up from what you already have?

Answer (score 0):

I think a way, is to insert in a temporally table all your items on basket, and then join it and get the products. So, if you have three times a product, you will got it inserted three times, and the join will be three times, so when you make the sum, will get the correct import.

This is if you're passing every Id as parameter from `PHP`

I'm not sure about `MySQL` syntax, but this should work

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE BasketProducts(Id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL)

Insert into BasketProducts values (--Insert everyId)
```

Then do the join

```
Select sum(P.price) from Products P
inner join BasketProducts  BP on P.Id = BP.Id
```